# Sumar los valores de una matriz en forma de M

Tags: python

Se necesita sumar los elementos de una matriz en forma de *M* de una matriz impar, es decir si se tiene una matriz de

> [1,5,7
>  2,3,4
>  6,8,9]

se debe sumar el 6,2,1,3,7,4,9

```
import random
for i in range(5):
  m.append([])
  for j in range(5):
    m[i].append(random.randint(1,9))
for i in m:
  print(i,end=" ")
  print()
print("")
```

Comment: divide y vencerás...una función que sume una columna i de tamaño m y otra que sume en diagonal desde x,y hasta +-n pasos

Comment: Para una matriz grande, hay varias maneras de hacer una "M". Te falta explicar ese detalle.